# My python package not installing dependent packages when my package is installed

Tags: setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I'm building a python package and have listed all of my dependent packages in a few different places... which I feel is probably redundant to achieve what I'm trying to. When I install my package, my dependencies are not being installed. super grateful for the assistance.

My package structure looks like this

```
root v
     src
        v
        ... (project files)
        setup.py
        setup.cfg
        requirements
                   v
                   requirements.txt
      pyproject.toml
```

my setup.py, setup.cfg, and pyproject.toml are pretty much synonymous, below is the content

`setup.cfg`

```
[metadata]
name = t-extractlib
version = 0.0.5
author = Trae Moore
author_email = my.email@gmail.com
description = A package standardized for extracting data from PDFs
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
url = https://github.com/traemoore/extractlib
license = MIT
classifiers =
    Programming Language :: Python :: 3
    License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License
    Operating System :: OS Independent

[options]
packages = find:
install_requires =
    nltk==3.8.1
    PyMuPDF==1.21.1
    camelot-py==0.11.0
    opencv-python==4.7.0.72
    ghostscript==0.7
python_requires = >=3.10
```

`setup.py`

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

```
with open("README.md", "r", encoding="utf-8") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setup(
    name="t-extractlib",
    version="0.0.5",
    author="Trae Moore",
    author_email="my.email@gmail.com",
    description="A package standardized for extracting data from PDFs",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/traemoore/extractlib",
    project_urls={
        "Bug Tracker": "https://github.com/traemoore/extractlib/issues",
    },
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        "setuptools>=61.0",
        "nltk==3.8.1",
        "PyMuPDF==1.21.1",
        "camelot-py==0.11.0",
        "opencv-python==4.7.0.72",
        "ghostscript==0.7"
    ],
    python_requires=">=3.10",
 )`
```

`pyproject.toml`

```
[build-system]
requires = [
    "setuptools>=61.0",
    "nltk==3.8.1",
    "PyMuPDF==1.21.1",
    "camelot-py==0.11.0",
    "opencv-python==4.7.0.72",
    "ghostscript==0.7"
]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "t-extractlib"
version = "0.0.5"
authors = [
  { name="Trae Moore", email="my.email@gmail.com" },
]
description = "A package standardized for extracting data from 
PDFs"
readme = "README.md"
 requires-python = ">=3.10"
 classifiers = [
    "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
    "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
    "Operating System :: OS Independent",
]

[project.urls]
 "Homepage" = "https://github.com/traemoore/extractlib"
 "Bug Tracker" = "https://github.com/traemoore/extractlib/issues"
```

here is an image of my directory structure

[image]

I have pushed the latest to `https://github.com/traemoore/extractlib` if you need to pull it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [this setuptools documentation](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html), you're not correctly setting the dependencies for the project; it needs to go under the [project] heading. You've currently got them under the [build-system], which means they get installed in the virtual environment used to build your project, not in the environment to run it.

It's also not really a good idea to have all three of those simultaneously. You can delete the `setup.py` and `setup.cfg`, and use *only* the pyproject.toml file, which is considered the standard form of specifying project metadata in Python now.

Here's the PEP for the [[build-system]](https://peps.python.org/pep-0518/) that you are using

Here's the PEP for [project metadata in pyproject.toml file](https://peps.python.org/pep-0621/)

Comment: Whenever possible, you should not link to the PEPs but to the actual specifications. At least for PEP 621 there is a warning in the PEP itself not to link to it. Use the link to the actual specification: [project metadata](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/declaring-project-metadata/)